# Can't install anything on ubuntu. Dependency error

Tags: apt

```
   linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 : Depends: linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-59-generic but it is not going to be installed
```

I am facing this error after trying to install Laravel. I don't know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install -f
```

Upon running the install command above, Ubuntu’s package manager will try to fix the dependency issues you are facing, and print out the changes it’s going to make. Read through the on-screen prompt that the terminal prints out. Then, when you’re done reading the on-screen prompt, press Y on the keyboard to continue.

Let the Apt packaging tool install the various software dependencies required to set your program up. Alternatively, if Apt can’t find any of the missing software dependencies it needs to work, it will automatically uninstall the app. If this is the case, consider trying to find the app through other means, rather than a DEB package.

Comment: dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-59-generic_5.3.0-59.53~18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):

Comment: It ran but gave this error.

Comment: It says operation not permitted. E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Method 1: Reconfigure Package Database

The first method you can try is to reconfigure the package database. Probably the database got corrupted while installing a package. Reconfiguring often fixes the problem.

[sudo dpkg --configure -a]

Method 2: Use force install

If a package installation was interrupted previously, you may try to do a force install.

[sudo apt-get install -f]

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04

Comment: [sudo dpkg --"packageName"]
[sudo apt-get update]
[sudo apt-get -f install]

Comment: what is the package name here linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04

Comment: try to use linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 –

Comment: dpkg: error: unknown option --linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04